# Repeat a row according to the specific cell value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table like this.

```
year   month    TenDays   TotalPerTenDays
------------------------------------------
96     9         3         12
96     10        1         15
96     10        3         22
96     11        1         2
96     11        2         10
96     11        3         1
96     12        1         13
```

I am trying to have a query with this result but ...

```
year   month    TenDays   TotalPerTenDays
------------------------------------------
96     9         1         0
96     9         2         0
96     9         3         12
96     10        1         15
96     10        2         0
96     10        3         22
96     11        1         2
96     11        2         10
96     11        3         1
96     12        1         13
96     12        2         0
96     12        3         0
```

Current query

```
SELECT dbo.DateTable.Year,
       dbo.DateTable.Month,
       dbo.DateTable.TenDays,
       Sum(dbo.ChequeItemTreasurer.ChequeTreasurer) AS TrTotalMonth
FROM   dbo.DateTable
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ChequeItemTreasurer
                    ON dbo.DateTable.ShamsiDateLong = dbo.ChequeItemTreasurer.ChequeDateTreasurer
GROUP  BY dbo.DateTable.Year,
          dbo.DateTable.Month,
          dbo.DateTable.TenDays
ORDER  BY dbo.DateTable.Year,
          dbo.DateTable.Month,
          dbo.DateTable.TenDays
```

Would you please help me for this?
(SQL 2014)
Thanks

Comment: Did you try yourself? Please write some description about your result?

Comment: I prepared a date table and joint them together but in this way i will have a big table as result and cause to my data filtering will be very hard. :(

Comment: please informed that i am trying to find a way without using date table.
in my data structure i have to calculate budget and cash flow in several period in a month ( 5 days/ 10 days/ 15 days per month) and it will be necessary that empty periods without financial transaction be in table with 0 value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a number / tally table.

```
; with 
qry as
(
    -- your existing query
    SELECT  dbo.DateTable.Year, 
        dbo.DateTable.Month, 
        dbo.DateTable.TenDays, 
        SUM(dbo.ChequeItemTreasurer.ChequeTreasurer) AS TrTotalMonth 
    FROM    dbo.DateTable 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ChequeItemTreasurer     
                     ON dbo.DateTable.ShamsiDateLong = dbo.ChequeItemTreasurer.ChequeDateTreasurer 
    GROUP BY dbo.DateTable.Year, dbo.DateTable.Month, dbo.DateTable.TenDays 
    ORDER BY dbo.DateTable.Year, dbo.DateTable.Month, dbo.DateTable.TenDays
)
select  q.Year, q.Month, TenDays, TrTotalMonth
from    qry q

union all

select  q.Year, q.Month, n.n as TenDays, TrTotalMonth = 0
from    qry q
        cross join num n    -- num is a number / tally table
where   q.tendays   >= n.n
and not exists
    (
        select  *
        from    qry x
        where   x.year      = q.Year
        and x.Month     = q.Month
        and x.TenDays   = n.n
    )
order by Year, Month, TenDays
```

Comment: not really. Cause the `TenDays` value should be from the `DateTable` not necessary always `1 , 2 , 3`

Answer (score 4):

Something like this

```
SELECT a.year,
       b.month,
       tc.TenDays,
       COALESCE(b.TotalPerTenDays, 0)
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT year,month
        FROM   yourtable) a
       CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(2),(3)) tc (TenDays)
       LEFT JOIN yourtable b
              ON a.year = b.year
                 AND a.month = b.month
                 AND tc.TenDays = b.TenDays
```

Your original query should be converted to something like this

```
SELECT dt.Year,
       dt.Month,
       tc.TenDays,
       Sum(ct.ChequeTreasurer) AS TrTotalMonth
FROM   (select distinct Year, Month, ShamsiDateLong from dbo.DateTable) dt
       CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(2),(3)) tc (TenDays)
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ChequeItemTreasurer ct
                    ON dt.ShamsiDateLong = ct.ChequeDateTreasurer
GROUP  BY dt.Year,
          dt.Month,
          tc.TenDays
ORDER  BY dt.Year,
          dt.Month,
          tc.TenDays
```

start using `alias` name, it makes the query more readable..

Answer (score 1):

Please try this, i got it right :)

```
   SELECT Table2.year,
               Table2.month,
               Table2.TenDays,
               ISNULL(YourTable.TotalPerTenDays,0)
  FROM (SELECT 
 DISTINCT Year,Month,Table1.TenDays
FROM   (SELECT 1 AS TenDays UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) AS Table1
CROSS JOIN YourTable)  AS Table2
 LEFT JOIN YourTable
            ON(YourTable.year         =             Table2.year
            AND YourTable.month =               Table2.month
            AND YourTable.TenDays = Table2.TenDays)
```